# Custom URL Routing to Handle Optional Parameter with C# Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm having issues navigating to my `ListPeople` method using the `URL`. If I type `localhost:12345/People?peopleId=405&age=24` into my `URL` it works fine; however, when I pass `localhost:12345/People?peopleId=405` into my `URL`, it returns a `404` error.

> **404 Error Message:**
>
> `"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI'http://localhost:12345/People?peopleId=405'."`

How can I change the routing of my `ListPeople` controller so that it excepts **BOTH** url's?

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
[ReturnDescription("List of People")]
[CustomActionName("")]
[Description("List of people  for given peopleId and age")]
public ApiResponse<Status, IEnumerable<People>> ListPeople(int peopleId, int? age)
{
    return _personProject.ListPeople(peopleId, age);
}
```

**Successful URL**

```
localhost:12345/People?peopleId=405&age=24
```

**Failing URL**

```
localhost:12345/People?peopleId=405
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is written, you have a method that represents the url:

```
/People?peopleId={0}&age={0}
```

You have to make an overload that will only accept `peopleId` because a method can only be the target of one route when you're setting it up automatically like this. What I would advise would be to make a simple overload:

```
public ApiResponse<Status, IEnumerable<People>> ListPeople(int peopleID)
{
    return ListPeople(peopleId, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry i can't write comment.So I must write here.If you'r using api Check your WebApiConfig. You must define your parameters in this config.

Like;

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{peopleid}/{age}",
            defaults: new { peopleid = RouteParameter.Optional, age = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Just an example. I think i can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help @CoderWho. I ended up using the answer above, but gave you an up arrow! :)